# first names in apacite citations

Tags: bibtex

I've got a LaTeX document with two BiBTeX references, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{Hurd2011,
author = {Hurd, Michael and van Rooij, Maarten and Winter, Joachim},
doi = {10.1002/jae},
journal = {Journal of Applied Econometrics},
pages = {416--436},
title = {{Stock Market Expectations of Dutch Households}},
volume = {26},
year = {2011}
}
@article{Hurd2012,
author = {Hurd, Michael D. and Rohwedder, Susann},
journal = {NBER Working Paper},
number = {17973},
title = {{Stock Price Expectations and Stock Trading}},
url = {http://www.nber.org/papers/w17973},
year = {2012}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
 \item \citet{Hurd2011}
 \item \citet{Hurd2012}
\end{itemize}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following list:

[image: reference list 1]

For some reason the first name of the first author appears in both citations. It shouldn't.

What's weird is that when I remove the 2012 reference (removing the in-text citation will do) the remaining 2011 reference is displayed correctly:

[image: reference list 2]

Why is this so and how do I get both to display correctly when both are present?

Comment: It's dawning on me that this is how it's supposed to be. Could it be that when two authors have the same last name but different first names (in this case they really are the same person but one is missing the middle initial) that first names are used in-text to distinguish between the two?

Comment: To BibTeX, “Michael D. Hurd” and ”Michael Hurd” are different people.